# docker compose with swarm - is it obsolete?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using docker compose to load up services on the swarm currently.  Is this now obsolete?  I am curious whether the approach is right going forward.  compose gives me a great deal of configurability in deploying to a stack and it is in one place for anybody to maintain.  There are great advantages.  However, I wonder if this is the approach adopted by the community.  Insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose approach is the standard way to use docker with swarm. It is by no means obsolete.

Comment: Good to get a corroboration!

Answer (score 0):

The simplified version of Docker swarm was introduce in 1.12 and the docker deploy with compose file command was introduced in 1.13. If you see the official documentation on https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#create-the-example-application

The sample compose file that they use is

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/stackdemo
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
```

So this definitely what the docker team wants us to use. And you are in the right direction.

Comment: Good to get a corroboration